# Linq to Entities - how to delete many records with inner join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have two classes:

```
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_Address { get; set; }

    public string URL { get; set; }
```

and:

```
public class Category_Address
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_Category_Address { get; set; }



    public int ID_Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public int ID_Address { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

}
```

I want to select `ID_Address` from `Address` table where `URL = "anytextIwrite"` and delete every record in `Category_Address` having the same `ID_Address` that I selected. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Now I wrote this with a few assumptions.  Obviously you'll want to use your own database names and whatever group names you want for them, but this is a fairly simple LINQ statement and join, followed by a foreach that should do what you want.

```
var toDelete = from addr in addresses
   join cate in category_addresses on addr.id_address equals cate.id_address
   where addr.url = "anytextIwrite"
   select cate;

foreach (var record in toDelete) {
    db.category_addresses.DeleteOnSumbit(record);
}
```

Comment: But I can't use a `DeleteOnSubmit()` method. Any idea why ?

Comment: Try this instead: webFormsEntities.DeleteObject(record);

Comment: I was missing a reference (System.Data.Linq).

Comment: No... it's not the reference. DeleteOnSubmit() doesn't work. I have ony a Remove() method, but using it makes an error.

Answer (score 0):

If still active, then try smth like this:

```
using (var context = new YourDbModel())
{
    var deletingAddresses = context.Category_Addresses
                                   .Where(ca => ca.Address.URL == "anytextIwrite")
                                   .Select(ca => ca.Address)
                                   .ToArray();
    foreach(var address in deletingAddresses)
    {
        context.Category_Addresses.Attach(address);
        var entry = context.Entry(address);
        entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It worked for me, so maybe you need the same.